# Design pattern to reuse the existing interface implementation in java

Tags: java, design-patterns

Suppose i have an interface

```
    public interface Action<T> {
        void doWork(T t);
    //can have multiple methods
    }
```

Now this class is implemented by

```
    public class DefaultAction implements Action<String> {
        @Override
        public void doWork(String s) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }
    }
```

Now i have a flow which accepts action

```
public abstract class Flow<T> {

    void execute(T t){
        Action<T> action = getAction();
        action.doWork(t);
    }

    abstract Action<T> getAction();
}
```

so i have flow that accepts double

```
public class AnotherActionFlow extends Flow<Double> {

    @Override
    Action<Double> getAction() {
        return new AnotherActionSet();
    }
}
```

which in turn uses the default action

```
public class AnotherActionSet implements Action<Double> {

    DefaultAction defaultAction;

    @Override
    public void doWork(Double aDouble) {
        defaultAction.doWork(String.valueOf(aDouble));
    }
}
```

So in this case i have to always update the `AnotherActionSet` method whenever the action interface changes

Is their any workaround so that i can have the common logic to convert the double to string and then use the `DefaultAction`

Can any pattern help to convert the `AnotherActionSet` to `DefaultAction` in which i only specify `String.valueOf(aDouble)` so the values can be passed to `DefaultAction`
instead of writing same thing for every method

### Summary

I want to reuse use the logic inside the `DefaultAction` for other actions which are a wrapper around the `DefaultAction`

For eg;

```
public class AnotherActionSet2 implements Action<Long> {

    DefaultAction defaultAction;

    @Override
    public void doWork(Long long) {
        defaultAction.doWork(String.valueOf(long));
    }
}


public class AnotherActionSet3 implements Action<Integer> {

    DefaultAction defaultAction;

    @Override
    public void doWork(Integer int) {
        defaultAction.doWork(String.valueOf(int));
    }
}
```

As you can see i have to write the mapping each time manually, instead is it possible to just pass the function which converts the give class to string and then i can use `DefaultAction`

So i just define Function<Double,String> dToS and plug it to `DefaultAction` and don't need to define the method again

Comment: Your example is abstract enough that it's difficult to tell exactly what you are needing; additionally, the fact that you're apparently reinventing `Consumer` and don't seem to be familiar with lambdas suggests that this code may be mostly or entirely unnecessary.

Comment: If  `AnotherActionFlow extends Flow<Double>` does the same thing than `String`, then why simply not declaring it `extends Flow<String>` instead of doing workarounds?

Answer (score 1):

You can use Java 8 lambda to get something that is much easier and more expressive.

Basically your Action is the same as standard Consumer from JDK, only that the name of the method change.

Then defaultAction look like that:

```
Consumer<String> defaultAction = s -> {System.out.println(s);}
```

And so AnotherActionSet can be expressed like that:

```
Consumer<Double> anotherActionSet = s -> {defaultAction.accept(String.valueOf(aDouble));}
```

You also discover that flow and action are doing exactly the same (taking a T and returning nothing) so one of the notion is redundant. And you could write:

```
Consumer<Double> anotherActionFlow = anotherActionSet;
```